# Proving $K^*N \cup N = K^*N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $K$ and $N$ be two languages. I want to prove that: $K^*N \cup N = K^*N$, where $*$ denotes the Kleene closure.

My idea is to say that I can write : $N={ε}N= K^0 N$.

Being $K^0$ the language $K$ raised to the power $0$ by definition all languages raised to the power equal a set with $ε$.

Replacing $N$ in $K^* N \cup N$ and using simplification of sets we have $K^*N \cup K^0N = K^*N$.

Is everything right here? Am I doing something that I can't?
Thank you ((and I'm sorry I don't know how to put the $0$ up))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $K^0 = \{\epsilon\}$, but your sentence "using simplification of sets we have $K^*N \cup K^0N = K^*N$" hides the main argument.

Actually, you can simply observe that $N = \{\epsilon\}N$ and then, using distributivity,
$$
K^*N \cup N = K^*N \cup \{\epsilon\}N = (K^* \cup \{\epsilon\})N
$$
It remains to observe that $K^* \cup \{\epsilon\} = K^*$ since $\epsilon \in K^*$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: You're welcome.